# Raphael library: Rect element not clickable unless filled?

Tags: javascript, raphael

This is driving me kind of batty. The code:

```
var rect = this.paper.rect(0,0,this.width - 10,this.height - 10);

rect.click(function(event) {
    alert("hi");
});
```

Never fires the `click` event, but:

```
var rect = this.paper.rect(0,0,this.width - 10,this.height - 10).attr({fill: 'black', 'fill-opacity': 0})

rect.click(function(event) {
    alert("hi");
});
```

Will fire the `click` event. It seems the `rect` object must absolutely be filled to register the click. I have a big ole rect that I want clickable. What gives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fill it with invisible color, with an opacity of 0.1

```
var rect = this.paper.rect(0,0,this.width - 10,this.height - 10)
                     .attr({fill: 'black', 'fill-opacity': 0.1})
```

Comment: Yeah. I did this. Doesn't quite make sense why it needs any fill at all but this works.